# Where did /dev/video0 go?

Tags: pi-zero-w, raspicam

The Pi camera in my Pi Zero W stopped working. Possibly because `/dev/video0` vanished. Can anyone say why?

In the meantime I have these three devices instead ..

```
pi@easy:~ $ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 0 Oct 24 07:17 /dev/video10
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 1 Oct 24 07:17 /dev/video11
crw-rw---- 1 root video 81, 2 Oct 24 07:17 /dev/video12
```

I don't know what *they're* for. (does anyone?)

I am loading the `bcm2835-v4l2` driver at boot time, my `/etc/modules` is simple enough

```
i2c-dev
bcm2835-v4l2
```

The driver/module loads well enough, according to `lsmod`

```
pi@easy:~ $ sudo lsmod | grep bcm2835
snd_bcm2835            17068  0
snd_pcm                92916  1 snd_bcm2835
snd                    63223  3 snd_timer,snd_bcm2835,snd_pcm
bcm2835_codec          28684  0
v4l2_mem2mem           18877  1 bcm2835_codec
videobuf2_dma_contig    10303  1 bcm2835_codec
bcm2835_v4l2           35910  0
bcm2835_mmal_vchiq     20644  2 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2
vc_sm_cma              25091  1 bcm2835_mmal_vchiq
v4l2_common             7385  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_vmalloc       6084  1 bcm2835_v4l2
videobuf2_v4l2         16373  3 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem
videobuf2_common       37369  4 bcm2835_codec,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              182789  6 bcm2835_codec,v4l2_common,videobuf2_common,bcm2835_v4l2,v4l2_mem2mem,videobuf2_v4l2
```

and calling `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2` has an exit code of 0, and doesn't change the output of `lsmod`.

This is everything `dmsg` has to say about `bcm2835`

```
pi@easy:~ $ dmesg | grep bcm2835
[    0.000202] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 27)
[    0.093961] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.138816] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at (ptrval), dmachans=0x1
[    0.359298] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.361524] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
[    0.833807] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.834308] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=1000000
[    0.835720] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.836458] sdhost-bcm2835 20202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.868215] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    0.868235] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    0.946792] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    5.237667] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    5.270823] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    5.298441] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   10.650795] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   10.698862] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[   10.698885] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[   10.709040] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[   10.709062] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[   10.720060] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[   10.720081] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[   11.500167] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   11.652618] bcm2835_audio soc:audio: card created with 8 channels
```

Comment: What video hardware do you have? If it's an official Raspberry Pi 5MP or 8MP camera then you need to load the `bcm2835_v4l2` module with `sudo modprobe bcm2835_v4l2` (or by adding it to /etc/modules).

Comment: Good point. Clarification added to the question. I am loading `bcm2835-v4l2` at boot time via `/etc/modules`.

Comment: have you checked it's loaded OK? Check it with `sudo lsmod` or reload it with `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`.

Comment: Thanks @Dougie, I've added that too.

Comment: Run `sudo rpi-update && sudo reboot` if the 4.19.85+ kernel doesn't fix it you've either got a hardware problem or gpu_mem isn't set to a high enough value. Try setting `gpu_mem=128` and `start_x=1` in /boot/config.txt. Check the cable between the RPi and the camera. Run `vcgencmd get_camera` to check the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `vcgencmd get_camera` result.

It will return how many cameras are supported and detected. 
Normally you will get "supported=1 detected=1".

If you get "detected=0" then camera is not detected : double check your connection, ribbon cable integrity and orientation, or consider that a picamera can fry from times to times.

I never met "supported=0", but I suppose it would hint to a misconfiguration problem.

Comment: A new camera module, and the problem vanished. It had been running continuously for a year after all.

Comment: Update! When the new camera briefly exhibited the same issue, the fundamental issue came into focus: the `p5v04a` connector on the camera daughter board had come unplugged. Once replugged, both new and old cameras revived.